# Pulsed DC power calculation

Tags: current-measurement, measurement, voltage-measurement, power-measurement

I'm trying to measure the power consumption of my device using a shunt resistor. I'm measuring both the voltage over my shunt resistor and the source voltage. With a math function i'm trying to calculate the average power consumption. What is the best way to do this? I've tried by using the Mean function and RMS function. Since the results are so different i'm a bit confused. I think the Mean function is the way to go, but i can't figure our why the RMS value is so much higher? Attached you can find the measurements.
[image]

Comment: Multiply C1 with C2 using your scope’s math functionality. Then do mean of your resulting M1.

Comment: With square pulses, simply treat the mark and the space separately.